# error while using makemigration in django

Tags: django, migration, python-3.5, makemigrations

I am working on a development server running python3.5 and Django 1.11 with virtualenv

when I use "**python manage.py makemigrations**" I get this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/opt/hafez_bot/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import (
  File "/opt/hafez_bot/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.exceptions import MigrationSchemaMissing
  File "/opt/hafez_bot/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .migration import Migration, swappable_dependency  # NOQA
ImportError: No module named 'django.db.migrations.migration'`

please help me

---

I understood that it's about my "**manage.py**" file and it has nothing to do with migration. because the "python manage.py help" raises the same error

this is my "**pip freeze**" output:

```
certifi==2017.7.27.1
Django==1.11.6
djangorestframework==3.6.4
future==0.16.0
mysqlclient==1.3.12
python-telegram-bot==8.0
pytz==2017.2
```

Comment: You are using python 3.5

Comment: Wrong env maybe?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid   yes, i made a mistake. i'm using python 3.5.2

Comment: Is that the full traceback?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid yes.

Comment: Try opening up the django shell and type `import django.db.migrations.migration` and see if you get the error.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid   i get the same error:                
ImportError: No module named 'django.db.migrations.migration'

Comment: Then it isn't your manage.py. Work your way backwards through the chain. `import django.db.migrations` etc.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid i can import "django.db" but for "django.db.migrations" i get the same error

Comment: Can you make sure it is django 1.11 that is installed?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid i added pip freeze output to my question

Comment: Is your database set up properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed Django and I reinstalled it.
And the error fixed

Answer (score 0):

I learned a hard lesson and a valuable lesson as well, any time you might face a challenge raised by django with a line at the bottom that has the following component  `ImportError: No module named 'django.db.migrations.migration'` it would be good for you to note that django did not install well. So you will be forced to re-install django again so that all model migration files can be availed for migration.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes to remove the *.pyc files, people use the following command:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
```

This will delete the `migrations` folder in the `./venv` folder as well if venv folder happens to be inside the current folder.

Move `venv` folder to somewhere else.